# OpenXML - Powerpoint Is there an UpdateLinks or LinkFormat.AutoUpdate using open.xml?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I have a PowerPoint template that is currently linked to an excel documents for charts (using the copy paste link as excel Chart Object). 
I am successfully able to update the links to a new excel document reference, however I do not see a way to programmatically call the updatelinks() function that is available via Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation.

When I open up the document I see it prompt for auto update, but I would like to achieve these programmatically and then set the link format to AutoUpdate manual, but via openxml and not through the interopt. Is there a way to do it?

TIA
Iris

Comment: There is no built-in function no, you'll have to implement it yourself. Interop is using an instance of Office in the background, that's why the library is seemingly able to update TOC, pagenumbers, links etc. while it's actually Office itself doing it.

Comment: Do you know how I should go about it? other then recreating the charts or copying over? I am trying to avoid that. thanks!